# ¿Cómo hacer para que los comentarios se muestren en cada producto?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

estoy haciendo un proyecto de una tienda virtual. Avancé bastante, pero me trabé haciendo los comentarios y el rating con estrellas.

Tengo un componente Products en el que hago el map de todos los libros.
La card individual está en Product.
El detalle de cada uno de los libros se ve en Detail.
El form de comentarios y de estrellas para calificar está en Rating
En Firebase creé una colección de comments. Y también uso Firebase para que los usuarios se logueen.

Hasta ahora logré que los comentarios se registren en la colección y se muestren en la sección de comments de Detail. También se puede hacer el crud de comments.

¿Qué me falta?
No puedo hacer que cada comentario se guarde en el producto correspondiente. O sea, si alguien entra a un libro y hace un comentario sobre ese libro, aparece en la sección de comentarios de todos los libros y no solo de ese.

En cada comentario aparece el mail del usuario actual y no del usuario que lo hizo. Lo ideal sería que en lugar del mail aparezca el nombre, pero primero tengo que lograr que aparezcan los datos de quien hizo el comentario y no de quien está conectado.

En el comentario no se guarda la calificación que hace el usuario con las estrellas, y aparece 0.

Intenté con varios tutoriales y no logré avanzar. Si alguno quiere ayudarme, puede ver todo el código en https://github.com/nicobonder/tienda

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Nico, recuerda revisar[esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que conozcas las normas para realizar una pregunta que sea aceptada por la comunidad.

Comment: Creo q con javascript puro las cosas serían mas faciles

Comment: Hola @DjCrazy, disculpa no encontré nada que indique que mi pregunta no es válida. Tienes alguna sugerencia? Gracias.

Comment: @LordXedriantheHigher pero ya tengo todo en React, sería bastante difícil volver a hacer todo y pasarlo a JS.

Comment: Entiendo. Es dificil cambiar de tecnologia cuando tienes tantas cosas hechas. Yo detesto a los frameworks por todo lo q conlleva su uso: falta de control, codigo innecesario acumulado, pueden quedar obsoletos si aparece uno mejor q les haga competencia, demasiados frameworks en el mercado que hacen lo mismo, etc.